# App Engine and models with relationships with python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, model, google-cloud-datastore

I've read some of the google docs about modeling (btw I'm a newbie with python and GAE/webapp2). Doing this with relationships would be a lot easier but I'm trying to learn google app engines, with the datastore and/or ndb.

Trying to do: I have a home with several zones, each zone has a group of sensors (light, moisture, tmp) that take readings and then send them to the server.

Something like this:

```
Class User(db.Model):
user = db.UserProperty()
usertype = db.StringProperty()(aka mom/father/child)

class Home(db.Model):
zone = db.IntegerProperty() #Zones in home unique int
zonename = db.StringProperty() # optional name for the zone

class Zone(db. Model):
sensortype = db. key or name? # I'd like to model moisture/tmp/light sensors that will be hereSensors in zone (from class sensors ?)
SensorID = #Ideally a key for that sensor in the zone ? 
DateCreated = db.DateProperty()

class Sensors(db.Model): # this will get the actual readings when they come in
Sensortype (moisture, tmp, light)
timeReading = db.DateProperty()
Reading = db.FloatProperty()
```

Later on I will want to read all temperature readings (from all zones or individual zones), many sensors, or individual sensors. be able to sort by date/time. I will compare these readings with weather reports also.

I'm having trouble figuring out if I should use a Structured object, keys with parents/ancestors , or the ReferenceProperty.

Where to start? I'm at a loss as to best model this.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using ancestors or reference properties in Google App Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123511/using-ancestors-or-reference-properties-in-google-app-engine)

Comment: In your specific example I would be making Home and ancestor of zone, and zone and ancestor of sensor, and not have any reference properties at all between them.  Sensors are fixed in space, in a zone, and zone in a home.  Having said that adjust your model to suit you access patterns.  Just my 2c ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was thinking the same but wanted confirmation. Does it make sense to use the StructuredProperty for sensors/zones or no ? I saw that in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#computed

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked many times.  Try searching for it in StackOverflow.

Here's a couple of answers, which in turn contain links to other answers.

[What is the purpose of ancestors in the google app engine datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832782/what-is-the-purpose-of-ancestors-in-the-google-app-engine-datastore)

[Using ancestors or reference properties in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123511/using-ancestors-or-reference-properties-in-google-app-engine)

Comment: Thanks for the find @dragonx. Can an admin mark this as a duplicate question?